# Falling from long distances can make Phaser sprite to ignore collision over Tiles in Arcade Physics?

Tags: collision-detection, collision, phaser-framework, tile

So I made a really simple platformer game, made the map with Tiled. Then my character is a sprite with ARCADE Physics that I make it jump across the map.

But I noticed that whenever it falls from let's say 12 tiles tall that are 64x64, whenever it hits the floor it will pass directly through it and completely ignoring collision detection.

Do you guys know what could be happening?

If you need specific parts of the code, let me know, but code itself is quite basic, the only complex thing i've been implementing is the jumping logic. But overall it's a simple Sprite with arcade physics enabled.

I just uploaded a [screen record](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Lty4qSTZC0) of the game. I jump not from far the first time and it doesn't happen, but when I do it slightly higher, it happens.

According to some googling, it seems to be related to the acceleration and collision detection. If sprite goes too fast, collision might not get detected, hence, it goes through the tiles.

Some people suggested using `game.physics.arcade.TILE_BIAS`, but is not recognizing at all that property, it won't compile.
Also suggested me playing with `body.maxVelocity (px/s)` or set `body.deltaMax (px/frame)` but i'm not quite sure what values to set it to in order to avoid this issue. Seems to be a bug since 2015.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this? To me it might be a problem in the future of my game.

Comment: The velocity of your character is probably so high that the collision check values are completely skipped over. For instance if it is checking collision at the value 0, maybe the character is going so fast, that there is not a moment in calculation where distance for collision would be 0, maybe it goes from 10 directly to a position of -10

Comment: Wow... so what do you recommend? Reduce falling velocity?

Comment: Considering I cant verify whether or not it is true, it was the first thing to come to mind. I would maybe set a maximum fall velocity, not necessarily reduce it.

Comment: with this.body.maxVelocity ? i tried changing from 10 to 500 but i always seem to get the same result for velocity when falling.

Comment: You would want to make max velocity smaller.

Comment: Yea, i tried even 10 and it was like if i wasn't changing anything.. mmm weird.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but mine was fixed with the TILE_BIAS property. Where in your code did you try to use TILE_BIAS?

Comment: Inside my player.ts code, on the constructor, where i do have access to game object, also tried to use it on the general gameplay.ts, didn't work either.

Comment: Same issue in my phaser 3.70 game, update